# How can I find "Firefox updates:" option in "firefox preferences > Advanced > update" tab

Tags: firefox, updates

I'm new for ubuntu, using firefox-11.0 in ubuntu-10.10, recently I removed ffox-3.6 and installed ffox-11.0 from superuser.  Even I cann't find update options in firefox preferences > Advanced > update...

there is no "Firefox updates:" option, only there is Automatically updates: search Egnines.

How can I find "Firefox updates:" option in "firefox preferences > Advanced > update" tab.

Comment: If you're new to Ubuntu, you should not be installing software from anywhere other than Ubuntu's Software Center, IMO. I'm saying this because I don't know what you mean by "installed ffox-11.0 from superuser."

Answer (score 4):

Hi and welcome to Ubuntu and Askubuntu :)

You'll be able to update your Firefox from the Update Manager when a newer version of Firefox is out and updated in the repositories. You can find the Update Manager from the Unity Dash - Press <kbd>Super</kbd> key and type `Update Manager` and click on the icon that shows up. Any and all packages that have an update will show up there and you can update them if you choose from there.

Do remember to click on the `Check` button and then clicking on the `Install Updates` button, that way the repositories get checked for updates and then you can install updates of your choice cleanly.

[image: dash]

[image: update-manager]

Comment: Hi, thanks....  but, I want to know, how can I view the "firefox updates:" option in browser at edit menu > preferences > Advanced > update tab) ...  pls...

Comment: That option is **not** available and therefore is **not** visible with the version of Firefox that comes by default with an Ubuntu installation. The "Ubuntu" Firefox is different in a few ways from the Firefox for generic Linux available directly from [Mozilla](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/).

Answer (score 0):

About:config  app.update.enabled 
see: http://kb.mozillazine.org/App.update.enabled and related entries will give you some options on this. It will not enable the checkmarks in the GUI however.